# Calculating particle equilibrium using Monte Carlo

Tags: algorithm, matlab, simulation, probability, montecarlo

I am trying to write a function that calculates the number of iterations it takes for two chambers to have equally as many particles.The evolution of the system is considered as a series of time-steps, beginning at t = 1. At each time-step exactly
one particle will pass through the hole, and we assume that the particles do not interact. The probability that
a particle will move from the left to the right chamber is pLR = NL/N, and the probability of a particle will
move from the right to the left chamber is pRL = 1 − pLR = (N − NL)/N.

The simulation will iteratively proceed as follows:

1. Get a random number r from the interval 0 ≤ r ≤ 1.
2. If r ≤ pLR, move one particle from the left to the right chamber. Otherwise move one particle from the
   right to the left chamber.
3. Repeat step 1 and 2 until NL = NR. Report back, how many time-steps it took to reach this equilibrium

This is my code thus far.

```
function t = thermoEquilibrium(N, r) %N = number of particles, r = random numbers from 0-1
h = []; %right side of the chamber
v = []; %left side of the chamber
rr = r;
k = false
NL=N-length(h) %This is especially where i suspect i make a mistake.
%How can the probability change with every iteration?
pLR = NL/N;
pRL = 1 - pLR;
count = 1
while k==false

for i = r
    if i<=pLR
        h(end+1)=i
        rr = rr(rr~=i)

    end
end

for l = h
    if pRL>l
       v(end+1) = l
       h = h(h~=l)
    end
end
if length(h)==N/2 && length(v)==N/2
       k=true
end
count = count + 1        
end

t = count
```

Can someone point me in a direction, so i can get a bit closer to something that works?

Comment: What is the issue you are having with your current code?

Comment: The current code seems to run in an infinite loop, and i suspect it is partly because i dont know how to make NL vary during everyloop